# Distorted display of Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

What is wrong with my map?
Please go to  [gtob.openfile.ch/mitglieder](https://gtob.openfile.ch/mitglieder), click on «A-Z», then on «Screenbox Multimedia Ltd.». Finally click on the button «Show map», than the same map is displayed in three div's. In the middle div, the map is distorted, and i can not find out why... (Responsive design is not finished now, please show with a screen-width of at least 1200 pixels)

Ok, here is the JavaScript/jquery for building the map:

```
var memberGoogleMapsData             = new Object;
memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer    = $(this).closest('div').find('div.memberMap');
$(this).closest('div').find('button').on('click', function() {
    memberGoogleMapsData.mapsPosLat     = parseFloat(memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer.data('mapsposlat'));
    memberGoogleMapsData.mapsPosLng     = parseFloat(memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer.data('mapsposlong'));
    memberGoogleMapsData.mapsZoom         = parseInt(memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer.data('mapszoom'));
    memberGoogleMapsData.markerPosLat     = parseFloat(memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer.data('markerposlat'));
    memberGoogleMapsData.markerPosLng    = parseFloat(memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer.data('markerposlng'));
    memberGoogleMapsData.mapId            = memberGoogleMapsData.mapContainer.prop('id');

    memberGoogleMapsData.mapPos = new google.maps.LatLng(memberGoogleMapsData.mapsPosLat, memberGoogleMapsData.mapsPosLng);
    memberGoogleMapsData.options = {
            zoom:       memberGoogleMapsData.mapsZoom,
            center:     memberGoogleMapsData.mapPos,
            mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            tilt:       0,
            heading:    0
    };

    memberGoogleMapsData.myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(memberGoogleMapsData.mapId),memberGoogleMapsData.options);
    memberGoogleMapsData.myMap2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('testMap'),memberGoogleMapsData.options);
    memberGoogleMapsData.myMap3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('testMap2'),memberGoogleMapsData.options);
});
```

In the div.memberMap I have data-Tags for providing the required data for building the google map:

```
<div class="memberMap" id="memberMap207" data-mapsposlat="47.50467769999999" data-mapsposlong="9.39942510000003" data-mapszoom="13" data-markerposlat="47.50467769999999" data-markerposlng="9.39942510000003">
```

Comment: Please past you code

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Why does I receive negative points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following style in the customer.css file

```
#members div.members img {
    float: right;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Your first map is inside the div.members, so this style breaks all the tile images of the map as well.

The second map that is outside of div.members is not affected by this style.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But after the image, I have a div (.clear) which clears the float. And to be sure, I received now the «float right» for the image, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You set maximum height of all images inside this div to 150px. Google maps images are 256px height.

Comment: xomena, you are my HERO!!! Thank you very much, this was the problem!!!